# Limit clause in mysql SP just take one parameter i.e. number of rows(offset)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have been trying to create a pagination with SP in mysql but I failed to do it using limit clause.
The starting point in limit case is never changed even if I  pass it in the query it self.

for eg. 'select * from abc where limit 30,60'

it starts with 1 first row till 60th row.

Here's my code that I have been working on

```
PROCEDURE theme_engine.paginate(IN upageno int(100))
BEGIN
DECLARE rstart int(10) ;
DECLARE rends int(10) ;
DECLARE squery varchar(200) ;
SET @rstart =(upageno - 1) * 15          ;
SET @rends = upageno * 15 ;
set @squery =concat('select * from primaryinfo limit ',rstart,',',rends );
SET @aa= @squery;
PREPARE STMT FROM @squery  ;

EXECUTE STMT  ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT         ;
END;
```

I have tested it with many debugging tool , read many articles to confirm this case.. but still If m wrong lee me know.

Comment: ur limit is always 30,60 as shown in ur SP,

Comment: no it changes as i pass one parameter to the SP

Comment: u have hardcoded the limits

Comment: it was just an example to show it doesn't work even if hard code it.

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't work. You say that it starts with the FIRST record but this SELECT is not ordered so it CAN start with any random record. Add `ORDER BY ID` where ID is a primary key or any field and then check if `LIMIT 30,60` works.

Comment: Yeah m pretty sure..i did all the possible ways ..

Comment: What is the MySQL version?

Comment: m using mysql 5.5.24..

Answer (score 0):

`select * from primaryinfo limit 1,60`

Answer (score 0):

Try this variable for ur query. Concat start and end limit of the query

```
 set @squery =concat('select * from primaryinfo limit ',rstart ,' , ',rends);
```

instead of : `set @squery =concat('select * from primaryinfo limit 30,60' );`

Comment: I did it intentionally to check weather it gives correct result or not..now made it dynamic....

Answer (score 0):

You can use your procedure parameters directly. From the documentation - *Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL 5.5.6.*

[MySQL 5.5: SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

Comment: by ready the article you posted, the same i read... I even tired and checked my code twice if I was wrong somewhere..but it didn't worked...

Comment: Adding to your code - you use `rstart` and `rends` variables which are NULL. Chnage them to `@rstart` and `@rends`.